# excel native database query - popup message accept by default?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

We have a direct link from excel to our redshift database - which is awesome.

However when we refresh data, users have to click through a lot of "accept" type windows, selecting Run (screencap below)

Any idea how to set this to accept by default?

Official doc on native queries doesnt seem to mention it: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Import-Data-from-Database-using-Native-Database-Query-Power-Query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00

[image: exce]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting DisplayAlerts to False will cause Excel to automatically choose the "default" option for all popups*, which for Native Database Queries is the Run option.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Remember it to set it back to True after running the query.

This solves your problem of automatically accepting these windows.

However, it may cause a separate problem of not allowing users to enter credentials if required and simply cancels the process instead. This can be solved with error handling if required. Before running the query, set an error handler:

```
On Error GoTo EnterCredentials
```

And at the end of the Subroutine, have an error handling block that re-enables DisplayAlerts so that the necessary prompt to enter a password becomes available. Note that the error handling block must use "Resume" instead of "Resume Next", as you want Excel to try the connection again with alerts being displayed.

The example error handling block below uses a boolean variable bolTriedPassword to keep track of whether the error has been raised previously, to display a more appropriate error message to the user. (It also has the server name saved to variable strServerName.)

It gives the user an option to Cancel to escape an otherwise never-ending loop and automatically ends entirely for other types of connection errors. You'll probably have to make some changes depending on your how your connection/login is set up, but it should get you started if needed.

```
Exit Sub

EnterCredentials:

If InStr(Err.Description, "credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid") > 0 Or Err.Number = 1004 Then
    'Network account doesn't have access. Allow alerts to display the login dialog. If Cancel is pressed, stop entirely.
    'If error occurs a 2nd time, then password was not entered correctly.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If MsgBox(IIf(bolTriedPassword, "A valid username and password were not entered for ", "Your network account has not been granted access to ") & strServerName & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        IIf(bolTriedPassword, "Please ensure you selected DATABASE as the login type and entered the correct username and password." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, "") & _
        "If you have a database username and password, press OK, then: " & vbCrLf & _
        " - Select DATABASE on the left of login window." & vbCrLf & " - Click RUN on the native query window.", _
        vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Error Establishing Connection") = vbCancel Then End
    bolTriedPassword = True
Else
    'For any other error, display error description and stop entirely
    MsgBox "Error connecting to SQL Server:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Establishing Connection"
    End
End If

Resume

End Sub
```

*Excel doesn't choose the default option for popups from SaveAs method, instead choosing the more useful option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts

> When using the SaveAs method for workbooks to overwrite an existing
>   file, the Confirm Save As dialog box has a default of No, while the
>   Yes response is selected by Excel when the DisplayAlerts property is
>   set to False. The Yes response overwrites the existing file.

Comment: fantastic works charm thanks!

good to learn about error handling in VBA as well, didnt know it was possible

Comment: You're welcome. VBA has poor error handling, but it's still important to know how to use it and how it behaves, especially for shared projects. A couple of good resources: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm and https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/